# How to grant another user Cloud deployment privileges for my FatFractal domain?

Tags: custom-backend

Is there a way to grant other FatFractal users Cloud deployment privileges on one of my domains? The domain/application are registered under my FatFractal account, and my partner is receiving 400 Errors (permission denied) from his FF local runtime engine when attempting to deploy an updated version of the app.

Also, is it possible to limit the scope of deployment privileges to a specific domain/application combo as opposed to the entire domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to the [FatFractal Console](https://system.fatfractal.com/console/application.html) and then click on "Invitations" in the menu, you can give other users read-only or read/write privileges to domains and applications.